# multi-cluster loki-stack export ingress

Tags: grafana, grafana-loki

How to export ingress in grafana/loki-stack(https://github.com/grafana/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/loki-stack) let central grafana could scrap log from the different clusters?
In the dev environment, I had install grafana and loki-stack, and add loki data source as http://loki.loki:3100
Now, I want stage environment loki-stack could be a data source of dev-grafana, but I don't know how to let stage-loki export ingress?
Does anyone have a similar experience could share with me?

Comment: Finally, I create an ingress.yaml file in loki-stack charts and apply this file, let loki server could be access from dev-cluster

Answer (score -1):

I deployed just loki and promtail in my dev cluster and can scrape the ingress from grafana in my production cluster

```
loki:
  enabled: true
  image:
    repository: myregistry.mynet/grafana/loki
    tag: 2.5.0
    pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
  persistance:
    enabled: true
    storageClassName: longhorn
    size: 50Gi
  ingress:
    enabled: true
    annotations:
      kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    hosts:
      - host: kube-dev.mynet
        paths:
          - /loki/
    tls:
    - secretName: kube-dev-mynet-secret
      hosts:
      - kube-dev.mynet
```